# Why is a folder created by WORKDIR owned by root instead of USER

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile

```
ARG DEV_USER=dev
# Other stuff ...
USER $DEV_USER
# Other stuff ...
WORKDIR /home/$DEV_USER/Projects
```

When I start a container and execute `ls /home/dev`, the `Projects` folder is owned by `root`. Does WORKDIR ignore the fact that USER was invoked earlier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I failed to find detail documents for this, but I'm interested on this, so I just had a look for [docker source code](https://github.com/moby/moby), I guess we can get the clue from sourcecode:

**moby/builder/dockerfile/dispatcher.go (Line 299):**

```
// Set the working directory for future RUN/CMD/etc statements.
//
func dispatchWorkdir(d dispatchRequest, c *instructions.WorkdirCommand) error {
    ......
    if err := d.builder.docker.ContainerCreateWorkdir(containerID); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return d.builder.commitContainer(d.state, containerID, runConfigWithCommentCmd)
}
```

Above, we can see it will call `ContainerCreateWorkdir`, next is the code:

**moby/daemon/workdir.go:**

```
func (daemon *Daemon) ContainerCreateWorkdir(cID string) error {
    ......
    return container.SetupWorkingDirectory(daemon.idMapping.RootPair())
}
```

Above, we can see it call `SetupWorkingDirectory`, next is the code:

**moby/container/container.go (Line 259):**

```
func (container *Container) SetupWorkingDirectory(rootIdentity idtools.Identity) error {
    ......
    if err := idtools.MkdirAllAndChownNew(pth, 0755, rootIdentity); err != nil {
        pthInfo, err2 := os.Stat(pth)
        if err2 == nil && pthInfo != nil && !pthInfo.IsDir() {
            return errors.Errorf("Cannot mkdir: %s is not a directory", container.Config.WorkingDir)
        }

        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Above, we can see it call `MkdirAllAndChownNew(pth, 0755, rootIdentity)`, next is the code:

**moby/pkg/idtools/idtools.go (Line 54):**

```
// MkdirAllAndChownNew creates a directory (include any along the path) and then modifies
// ownership ONLY of newly created directories to the requested uid/gid. If the
// directories along the path exist, no change of ownership will be performed
func MkdirAllAndChownNew(path string, mode os.FileMode, owner Identity) error {
    return mkdirAs(path, mode, owner, true, false)
}
```

Above will setup folder in intermediate build container & also change the ownership of the folder with `rootIdentity`.

Finally, what is `rootIdentity` here?

It's passed here as `daemon.idMapping.RootPair()`, next is the declare:

**moby/pkg/idtools/idtools.go (Line 151):**

```
// RootPair returns a uid and gid pair for the root user. The error is ignored
// because a root user always exists, and the defaults are correct when the uid
// and gid maps are empty.
func (i *IdentityMapping) RootPair() Identity {
    uid, gid, _ := GetRootUIDGID(i.uids, i.gids)
    return Identity{UID: uid, GID: gid}
}
```

See the function desc:

> RootPair returns a uid and gid pair for the root user

You can continue to see what `GetRootUIDGID` is, but I think it's enough now from the function desc. It will finally use change the ownership of `WORKDIR` to `root`.

And, additional to see what `USER` do?

```
__moby/builder/dockerfile/dispatcher.go (Line 543):__

// USER foo
//
// Set the user to 'foo' for future commands and when running the
// ENTRYPOINT/CMD at container run time.
//
func dispatchUser(d dispatchRequest, c *instructions.UserCommand) error {
    d.state.runConfig.User = c.User
    return d.builder.commit(d.state, fmt.Sprintf("USER %v", c.User))
}
```

Above, just set user to run config and directly commit for further command, but did nothing related to `WORKDIR` setup.

And, if you want to change the ownership, I guess you will have to do it by yourself use `chown` either in `RUN` or `ENTRYPOINT/CMD`.

Comment: IMHO this answer would be improved if it had a summary and/or conclusion included.

Answer (score -2):

Docker is always run as root user in its environment, SO instead we specify it to use another user.

So before running anything we can add a user to its environment then specify that useR to perform action in Dockerfile.

This example add user to www-data

```
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000

RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} www-data &&\
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g www-data www-data &&\
```