# Dockerfile permission denied in second layer

Tags: docker

I have two Dockerfiles

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /test
RUN touch abc.txt
USER 1001
```

The first builds fine

docker build -t myimage:foo .

```
FROM myimage:foo
WORKDIR /foo
RUN touch def.txt
USER 0
```

I get an error when trying to build the second.  Permission denied on the touch def.txt.

Why?

Comment: I'd guess that, when `WORKDIR` creates the directory, it's owned by root rather than the current `USER`, though this isn't specifically mentioned in [the `WORKDIR` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir).  Practically you probably want most things in an image to be owned by root even if you're executing as a different user.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone can correct me if i am wrong

In the first example the USER is set to 1001 and that is the App User which is you running it but in the second example it is different user which is not you and that person/uid doesn't have the right to change the file in the folder foo and the file def.txt

Answer (score -1):

Unlike `RUN mkdir /bar` which will use the `USER` of parent base image, `WORKDIR /foo` will use next identity to setup folder, that means the folder's owner is `root`, details refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980924/6394722)(**TLDR**):

```
// RootPair returns a uid and gid pair for the root user. The error is ignored
// because a root user always exists, and the defaults are correct when the uid
// and gid maps are empty.
func (i *IdentityMapping) RootPair() Identity {
    uid, gid, _ := GetRootUIDGID(i.uids, i.gids)
    return Identity{UID: uid, GID: gid}
}
```

So, for your next code:

```
WORKDIR /foo
RUN touch def.txt
```

`WORKDIR` set up `foo` with root permission, while `RUN touch` try to use `1001` account to set up a file in that root owned folder, surely failure.

For your case, you could workaround as next:

```
FROM myimage:foo
WORKDIR /foo
USER 0
RUN chmod 777 /foo
USER 1001
RUN touch def.txt
USER 0
```